# How to colorize transparency pixels of an image?

Tags: colors, alpha, colorize

I have a png image with an alpha channel and some transparent parts in it.
Now, what I would like to do is to colorize these transparent pixels with a color.
However, when I search in the internet for "alpha to color", nothing shows up but "color to alpha"! Does anybody know a way how to do this? Tools and programs for windows would be best.

Thanks a lot,

Mike

Comment: If it's an alpha channel, then some or all pixels might be *partially* transparent ("translucent", but nobody seems to use that term). Do you want to only affect *completely* transparent pixels, or do you want to put a colour "behind" the translucent image? Also, are you just looking for a manual tool to do this (which would be off-topic for a programming site), or do you need to automate this in some particular programming language?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to 'put a colour "behind" the translucent image'. For your second question: Yes, I am looking for a manual tool to do this, so sorry for asking an off-topic question :(

Comment: OK, that's definitely off-topic here then. It's also pretty easy in any decent graphics program (Paint.net, GIMP, PhotoShop, etc): open your file, add a new layer filled with the required colour behind the current image, save the result back out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about manual image manipulation, not anything programming related.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also found a program after searching: deranfaenger.github.io/Colorize-Alpha/googlee787835f3309cf9b.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, the program [Colorize-Alpha](http://deranfaenger.github.io/Colorize-Alpha/) also worked for me :)